# Detectar parámetro de ruta, Express (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ms-access, rutas

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación **Express** en **Node** en la cual necesito detectar si la ruta de la petición contiene un parámetro al final (endpoint) para cambiar el comportamiento del enrutamiento preestablecido, es decir, si tengo una petición **GET** en la ruta `/*` que se comporta de x forma, si la ruta contiene el parámetro `/puclic`, es decir `/*/public`, enviar una respuesta diferente.

En el siguiente código muestro como estoy intentando realizar esto.

**Código de ejemplo:**

```
//Pagina de inicio que funciona en la petición 

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("Inicio")
})

//Ruta(s) que contienen una respuesta preestablecida.  

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta predeterminada.")
});

//Ruta con endpoint que no envía respuesta modificada

app.get("/*/public", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta modificada.")
});
```

Lo que pasa en mi ejemplo es que en la ruta `"/"` me envia el "**Inicio**" como debería, e incluso utilizando otras rutas mas largas como `"/login/strategy"` me manda la respuesta esperada ("**Respuesta predeterminada**"), pero al utilizar `/*/public` entendiendo que **"*"** es todo lo que se encuentre en medio, fácilmente podría ser `"/login/strategy/public"` por ejemplo, no me manda la respuesta que deseo, en este caso "**Respuesta modificada**".

La respuesta a **porque estoy utilizando la ruta `"/*"` para las solicitudes:**

En realidad necesito que sea así porque estoy mapeando las rutas para obtener documentos Json y enviarlos al cliente, por lo que no soy capaz de utilizar parámetros fijos puesto a que los documentos cambian constantemente y las rutas son consultadas en el lado del cliente por el usuario.

La aplicación en si es funcional a través de mi método, pero si hay una mejor manera de obtener rutas no fijas y detectarlas para enviar respuestas acorde a el contenido de su url me gustaría escucharlo.

Ahora en cuanto al problema en si... ¿existe alguna manera de detectar el endpoint al final de la URL y cambiar su comportamiento utilizando rutas dinámicas con express en si?

**¡Muchas gracias!.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error no era mas que un error básico de principiantes en **JavaScript** y en la programación como tal que no se porque no me paso por la mente... pero ya esta solucionado.

**Para a quien pueda interesar**:

El problema estaba en la declaración de los enrutamientos de la app, el orden de estos siempre debe ser de arriba hacia abajo (*como todo*) y como mi ruta no es mas que un filtro pues, es imposible que filtre si esta declarada abajo de lo que quiero filtrar.

**Esto quiere decir:**

Si declaras las rutas separadas después del catch-all (`"/*"`), este se va a ejecutar primero, y va a enviar la respuesta como si el parámetro que queremos filtrar fuese parte de la ruta, en cambio si las ubicas antes de este, reciben los primeros pasos para manejar las solicitudes entrantes, por ende se evalúan primero, en este caso, filtra si la ruta contiene el parámetro `/puclic` al final.

**Código problemático (el de la pregunta):**

```
//Pagina de inicio que funciona en la petición 

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("Inicio")
})

//Ruta(s) que contienen una respuesta preestablecida.  

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta predeterminada.")
});

//Ruta con endpoint que no envía respuesta modificada

app.get("/*/public", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta modificada.")
});
```

**Como debe ser:**

```
//Pagina de inicio que funciona en la petición 

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("Inicio")
})

//Ruta con endpoint re ubicado.

app.get("/*/public", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta modificada.")
});

//Ruta(s) que contienen una respuesta preestablecida.  

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
  res.send("Respuesta predeterminada.")
});
```

Ahora como se evalúa primero tiene oportunidad de ejecutarse, por esto mismo la ruta `"/"` si respondía correctamente, pues estaba declarada antes en el router.

Gracias si intentabas conseguir cual era el problema.

Comment: No se entiende tu respuesta, añade una muestra del código donde estaba el fallo

Comment: Editado amigo, gracias por tu interés.